# Handling parenthesis while converting infix expressions to postfix expressions

Tags: java, postfix-notation, infix-notation

I'm working on a project in Java that requires me to convert an infix expression to a postfix expression. I am currently able to convert infix expressions to postfix with this method as long as they don't contain parenthesis, but I can't figure out how to handle parenthesis.

Basically, I have two stacks that hold objects that are called 'Token'. A Token is a wrapper class that holds a string that is either a number, variable (which gets evaluated as a number, pending on user input), operator (the operator has a priority level associated with it so that my method can determine how to handle order of operations between '+', '-', '*' and '/'), or a parenthesis (the parenthesis has a way to determine if it is a open parenthesis or a closed parenthesis).

How should I handle parenthesis? What about multiple layers of parenthesis?

```
public String toPostFix() {
    StringBuilder postfixstr = new StringBuilder();

    Stack<Token> in_fix = new Stack<>();
    Stack<Token> post_fix = new Stack<>();

    for (int i = tokens.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        t = new Token(tokens[i]);
        in_fix.push(t);
    }

    //there are still tokens to process
    while (!in_fix.empty()) {
        //is a number
        if (in_fix.peek().type == 1) {     
            postfixstr.append(in_fix.pop().toString());
        } 

        //is an operator and the stack is empty
        else if (in_fix.peek().type == 3 && post_fix.empty()) {   
            post_fix.push(in_fix.pop());
        } 

        // is an operator that has higher priority than the operator on the stack
        else if (in_fix.peek().type == 3 && in_fix.peek().isOperator() > post_fix.peek().isOperator()) {
            post_fix.push(in_fix.pop());
        } 

        // is an operator that has lower priority than the operator on the stack
        else if (in_fix.peek().type == 3 && in_fix.peek().isOperator() <= post_fix.peek().isOperator()) {
            postfixstr.append(post_fix.pop());
            post_fix.push(in_fix.pop());
        } 

        //puts the rest of the stack onto the output string
        if (in_fix.empty()) {
            while (!post_fix.empty()) {
                postfixstr.append(post_fix.pop());
            }
        }
    }

    return postfixstr.toString();
}
```

Comment: What you have is more or less the Dijkstra shunting-yard algorithm, but without the parenthesis handling.

Comment: Interesting. I'm looking into some literature on this right now!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to push the left parenthesis onto the stack, and process the stack like so when you encounter a right parenthesis:

```
// opening (
if (in_fix.peek().type == 4) {   
    post_fix.push(in_fix.pop());
}
//closing )
if(in_fix.peek().type == 5){
    while(!(post_fix.isEmpty() || post_fix.peek().type == 4)){
         postfixstr.append(post_fix.pop());
    }
    if (post_fix.isEmpty())
        ; // ERROR - unmatched )
    else
        post_fix.pop(); // pop the (
    in_fix.pop(); // pop the )
}
```

Comment: Definitely not me! haha.

Comment: @dg_no_9 *et al.* The joke escapes me. The only correct answer in the thread, and it has a downvote?

Comment: I guess yours and mine are similar answers, I think your answer is too right, that's why I've not downvoted you unlike you did to mine. :)

Comment: @dg_no_9 So you should correct your answer. Correct answers should be upvoted, not downvoted, that's my point. You can draw your own conclusion.

Comment: Yes. I've edited the answer after you showed me the errors in the answer, That's why I've already edited it.

Comment: Thank you very much! This works perfectly. =) I'd help up-vote, but my reputation is not high enough yet! hahahah

Answer (score 1):

Try this way:

```
    //opening Parenthesis 
        if (in_fix.peek().type == 4) {   
                    post_fix.push(in_fix.pop());
        }
        //closing Parenthesis 
        if(in_fix.peek().type == 5){
             //Till opening parenthesis encountered in stack, append operators to postfix. and pop parenthesis and do not append to post_fix.
             while(post_fix.peek().type!=4){
                 postfixstr.append(post_fix.pop());
             }
            //finally pop left parenthesis from post_fix stack.
            post_fix.pop();
        }
```

Comment: Doesn't look right. How will the while condition ever change?

Comment: sorry I got confused with the in_fix stack and post_fix stack. Now I've edited that. Thanks for the info. :)

Comment: Still not right. This will just append parentheses to the postfix. It should be `!= 4`. You also need to check for a missing right parenthesis (i.e. empty stack), and pop the (. I suggest you look it up.

Comment: This is not the exactly working copy of the code, I just wanted to give him/her an idea. That's why I've mentioned the logic in comments.

Comment: As I named the algorithm in comments half an hour ago, before your answer was even posted, it was hardly to 'get some idea' myself, and as I gave you several hints before downvoting, it was hardly that either. But enough is enough. Your latest edit is still inadequate.

Comment: You still need to consume the `)` from `in_fix.`

Comment: This answer is very good as well! Just the end is off, because I also have to apply the pop method to the in_fix stack. Thank you for the help though!