# Infix to Postfix(Reverse Polish Notation) conversion works with parentheses but not without

Tags: c#, postfix-notation, infix-notation

#### Rules of Assignment:

- Must have separate Operator class and separate PostFix class containing the conversion method.
- Evaluate left to right.
- Operators are placed into a Stack.
- Only binary operators
- Separate Operator class and PostFix class, where PostFix contains the Conversion method.
- C#

#### My Issue:

My conversion works if all/most of the equation is in parentheses. It works without parentheses only if the input is in the order of operations.

I believe I'm just not checking priority properly, but I'm not certain that's the issue. I've rewritten my conversion method 4 times now and spent around 25 hours tweaking and running through the debugger on different iterations of the method, and Googling, but I'm just not comprehending where the issue is in my code. I see it while debugging but I'm not sure what I have to do to fix it, so I figured maybe a third party's perspective would help.

#### Examples

Incorrect output:

```
a=5+3/4-(9*8-1)*1         =>        a 5 3 + 4 / 9 8 * 1 -  - 1 * = 
      should be       a 5 3 4 / + 9 8 * 1 - - 1 * =

alpha = beta + gamma * delta        =>        alpha beta gamma + delta * = 
      should be       alpha beta gamma delta * + =
```

Correct output:

```
a = ((((a+b)-c)*d)/(e+1))         =>        a a b +  c -  d *  e 1 +  /  = 

alpha = beta * gamma + delta         =>        beta gamma * delta + alpha =
```

#### My code

Operator class:

```
class Operator
{
    private byte precedence = 1;        //Precedence of operator over others
    private char identity = 'x';        //the character behind the operator

    /// <summary>
    /// Creates an operator based on the passed character
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="OperatorIn">Character definition of the operator</param>
    public Operator(char OperatorIn)
    {
        identity = OperatorIn;
        switch (OperatorIn)
        {
            case '*':
                precedence = 2;
                break;
            case '/':
                precedence = 2;
                break;
            case '(':
                precedence = 3;
                break;

            case ')':
                precedence = 3;
                break;

            case '=':
                precedence = 3;
                break;
            case '+':
                precedence = 1;
                break;

            case '-':
                precedence = 1;
                break;

            default:
                precedence = 0;
                break;
        }//switch
    }//Operator(char)

    /// <summary>
    /// Retrieves the char representation of the operator
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>Char representation of the operator</returns>
    public char ToChar()
    {
        return this.identity;
    }//ToChar()

    /// <summary>
    /// Returns the byte value of precedence of the operator
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>byte value of precedence</returns>
    public byte GetPrecedence()
    {
        return this.precedence;
    }
}//Operator
```

Conversion method:

```
public static string Convert(string infix)
    {
        #region original
        Stack<Operator> OpStack = new Stack<Operator>();
        String Postfix = String.Empty;
        InfixPostfix.Operator Previous = new Operator('x'),
                              Current = null;   //NextOp = new Operator(infix[infix.IndexOfAny(Ops, i)]);
        char[] Ops = {'+','-','=','*','/'};
        string term = String.Empty;

        foreach(char c in infix)
        {
            if (Ops.Contains(c))                        //if the char is one of the operator chars
            {
                Postfix += term + " ";                  //split term and add to output
                while (OpStack.Count > 0)               //While there's actually operators in the stack  
                {
                    Current = OpStack.Pop();            //Assign the operator as Current Operator
                    if (Current.GetPrecedence() < Previous.GetPrecedence())     //If Current Op is less priority than preceding Op
                        Postfix += Current.ToChar() + " ";                      //Output the character of the Op
                    else                                //If Current Op priority is higher than the previous
                    {
                        Previous = Current;             //Store the current as previous to move on
                        OpStack.Push(Current);          //Store current in stack
                        break;                          //Move to next char
                    }//else
                }//while
                OpStack.Push(new Operator(c));          //If stack is empty, push the operator
                term = "";                              // and reset the term to empty
            }//if
            else if (c == ')')                          //If the char is a close paren
            {
                Postfix += term + " ";                  //store the previous characters as a term in postfix
                term = "";                              //establish a new term
                Previous = Current;                     //Set Current as the old Op
                Current = OpStack.Pop();                //Get the new Current op
                while (Current.ToChar() != '(')         //Pop the stack until you get an open paren op
                {
                    Postfix += Current.ToChar() + " ";  //Add the term to the output string
                    //Previous = Current;
                    try
                    {
                        Current = OpStack.Pop();        //Try to pop another operator
                    }//try
                    catch(Exception)                    //If the stack is empty
                    {
                        return "Error! Mismatched parentheses!";    //Then there is a missing/misaligned paren
                    }//catch
                }//while
            }//else if
            else if (c == '(')                          //If the op is an open paren
                OpStack.Push(new Operator(c));          //store it
            else if (c != ' ')                          //If it's an alphanumeric char, 
                term += c;                              //build a term with it
        }//foreach
        Postfix += term + " ";                          //add the last term to the output
        while(OpStack.Count > 0)                        //If there are remaining ops on the stack,
        {
            Current = OpStack.Pop();                    //pop them off
            if (Current.ToChar() == '(' || Current.ToChar() == ')') //If there is a paren remaining
                return "Error! Mismatched parentheses!";            // it's because of missing complement or misalignment
            Postfix += Current.ToChar() + " ";              //if regular op, add to output
        }//while
        return Postfix;
    }
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Handling parenthesis while converting infix expressions to postfix expresssions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19721072/handling-parenthesis-while-converting-infix-expressions-to-postfix-expresssions)

Answer (score 0):

Alright, so, I got a few upvotes that indicated there was interest in the answer. My solution was once again trashing what I had and starting over. I sat down and went through the algorithm on paper multiple times then went through it while debugging one line at a time. This led to some "interesting" tweaks just to finish this.

Honestly, what I came up with is disgusting -- at one point I have a for-else if-if-if-while-if. So this thing isn't pretty, and probably is really inefficient. Luckily I don't get graded on efficiency in this class, haha. I just needed to get it done as it's due on Friday and I have an Assembly project to start. Anyway...

#### Code

Operator class has updated precedence values in the constructor.

```
public Operator(char OperatorIn)
    {
        identity = OperatorIn;
        switch (OperatorIn)
        {
            case '*':
                precedence = 2;
                break;
            case '/':
                precedence = 2;
                break;

            case '=':
                precedence = 1;
                break;
            case '+':
                precedence = 1;
                break;

            case '-':
                precedence = 1;
                break;

            default:
                precedence = 0;
                break;
        }//switch
    }//Operator(char)
```

Structure is similar for the Convert method. There's a lot of `if(Stack.Count>0)` checks which probably indicates bad logic inside loops and other if/whiles. But it seems to work perfectly.

```
public static string Convert(string infix)
    {
        Stack<Operator> OpStack = new Stack<Operator>();
        String Postfix = String.Empty;
        Operator Previous = new Operator('x'),
                 Current = null;
        char[] Ops = { '+', '-', '=', '*', '/' };
        string term = String.Empty;

        foreach (char c in infix)                           //Iterate through char at a time
        {
            if (c == '(')                                   //If open paren
                OpStack.Push(new Operator(c));              // put on the stack
            else if (c == ')')                              //If close paren
            {
                Postfix += term + " ";                      //Output the term
                term = "";                                  // and clear out the term holder
                Previous = OpStack.Peek();                  //Get a value to know Previous has as real value instead of 'x'
                while (Previous.ToChar() != '(')             // pop until we reach the open paren
                {
                    if (OpStack.Count > 0)
                        Current = OpStack.Pop();                //Current becomes what was on top of the stack
                    if(Current.ToChar() != ')' && Current.ToChar() != '(')
                        Postfix += Current.ToChar() + " ";       //  add to output
                    try                                          //Make sure we have more to pop
                    {
                        Previous = OpStack.Pop();                //Previous becomes what was 2nd on the stack
                    }//try
                    catch (Exception)                            //If there's nothing to pop and we're still in this loop
                    {
                        return "Error! Mismatched parentheses!"; //Mismatched or missing parenthesis
                    }//catch
                }//while
            }//else if
            else if (Ops.Contains(c))                       //If it's an operator
            {
                Postfix += term + " ";                      //output the term
                term = "";                                  // and clear the term holder
                Current = new Operator(c);                  //Assign the current character as Current Op
                if (OpStack.Count > 0)                      //If there are previous ops in stack
                {
                    Previous = OpStack.Peek();              // get top op on stack to compare

                    if (Previous.GetPrecedence() > Current.GetPrecedence() && OpStack.Count > 0)            //Decide between > and =
                    {
                        while (Previous.GetPrecedence() > Current.GetPrecedence() && OpStack.Count > 0)       //Pop until we find lesser precedence op
                        {
                            Previous = OpStack.Pop();           //Remove the compared value from stack
                            Postfix += Previous.ToChar() + " "; //Add the popped ops to output
                            if (OpStack.Count > 0)              //make sure we aren't looping too far
                                Previous = OpStack.Peek();      //assign new value before compare occurs
                        }//while 
                    }//if
                    else if(Previous.GetPrecedence() == Current.GetPrecedence() && OpStack.Count > 0 && Previous.ToChar() != '=')       //Decide between > and =
                    {
                        while (Previous.GetPrecedence() == Current.GetPrecedence() && OpStack.Count > 0 && Previous.ToChar() != '=')    //Pop until = precedence found
                        {
                            Previous = OpStack.Pop();           //Remove the compared value from stack
                            Postfix += Previous.ToChar() + " "; //Add the popped ops to output
                            if (OpStack.Count > 0)              //make sure we aren't looping too far
                                Previous = OpStack.Peek();      //assign new value before compare occurs
                        }//while
                    }//else if
                    OpStack.Push(Current);                  //Once a <= op is found, store the Current op
                    continue;
                }//if
                else                                        //If there are no ops on stack
                    OpStack.Push(Current);                  // store it immediately
            }//else if
            else if (c != ' ')                              //If alphanumeric
                term += c;                                  // add into term holder
        }//foreach
        Postfix += term + " ";                              //There will be a term left over after the final c, so output it
        while(OpStack.Count > 0)                            //There may also be ops left, so pop them
        {
            Current = OpStack.Pop();
            if (Current.ToChar() == '(' || Current.ToChar() == ')') //If there is a paren remaining
                return "Error! Mismatched parentheses!";            // it's because of missing complement or misalignment
            Postfix += Current.ToChar() + " ";                      //output the operator
        }//while
        return Postfix;
        }//Convert v2
```