# (JAVA) infix to postfix conversion and calculation

Tags: java, parentheses, postfix-notation, infix-notation, calculation

I am working on infix to postfix calculation. I came up with GUI with main.java, Evaluation.java for converting input infix to postfix and calculate, and DivisionException.java for dividing by 0. However, program itself is working fine, but calculation, checking the parenthesis pair, and DivisionException are not working properly. I cannot even tell if I wrote ActionListener method correctly or not. Please give me a hand.

//**Main.java**

```
    import java.awt.*;
    import java.awt.event.*;
    import javax.swing.*;
    import java.io.*;
    import java.util.*;

    public class Main extends JFrame{
private GridLayout glm = new GridLayout(3, 1, 5, 20);
private JPanel jp1 = new JPanel();
private JPanel jp2 = new JPanel();
private JPanel jp3 = new JPanel();
private GridLayout gl1 = new GridLayout (1, 2);
private JLabel jl1 = new JLabel("Enter Infix Expression", JLabel.CENTER);
private JTextField jtf1 = new JTextField();
private GridLayout gl2 = new GridLayout(1, 3, 5, 9);
private JButton jbEvaluate = new JButton("Evaluate");
private GridLayout gl3 = new GridLayout(1, 2);
private JLabel jl2 = new JLabel("Result", JLabel.CENTER);
private JTextField jtf2 = new JTextField();
private String postfixExpression;
private int result;

public String userInput(){
    return (String)jtf1.getText();
}

public Main(){
    setTitle("Infix Expression Evaluator");
    setSize(500, 200);
    setLayout(glm);
    jp1.setLayout(gl1);
    jp1.add(jl1);
    jp1.add(jtf1);
    add(jp1);
    jp2.setLayout(gl2);
    jp2.add(new JLabel(""));
    jp2.add(jbEvaluate);
    jbEvaluate.addActionListener(new EnterActionListener());
    jp2.add(new JLabel(""));
    add(jp2);
    jp3.setLayout(gl3);
    jp3.add(jl2);
    jp3.add(jtf2);
    jtf2.setEditable(false);
    jtf2.setBackground(Color.lightGray);
    add(jp3);
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    setResizable(true);
    setVisible(true);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
}

class EnterActionListener implements ActionListener{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae){
        try{
            if(userInput() == null){
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Paranthesis does not match", "Paranthesis Error", JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);    
                }
            else if(Evaluation.checkParenthesis(userInput()) == true){
            postfixExpression = Evaluation.InfixToPostfix(userInput());
            result = Evaluation.Calculation(postfixExpression);
            jtf2.setText(Integer.toString(result));
                }
            else if(Evaluation.checkParenthesis(userInput()) == false){
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Paranthesis does not match", "Paranthesis Error", JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
                }
            else if(userInput() == null){
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Paranthesis does not match", "Paranthesis Error", JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);    
                }
            }catch(DivisionException de){
                new DivisionException();
            }
        }
    }

public static void main (String[] args){
    Main main = new Main();
    }
}
```

//**Evaluation.java**

```
import java.util.*;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
public class Evaluation {

 public static String InfixToPostfix(String infixExpression){

    boolean numberEnd = false;
    String postfixExpression = "";
    Stack stack = new Stack();

    for(int i = 0; i< infixExpression.length(); i++){
        char infixExpChar = infixExpression.charAt(i);
        switch(infixExpChar){
        case '0':
        case '1':
        case '2':
        case '3':
        case '4':
        case '5':
        case '6':
        case '7':
        case '8':
        case '9':
            postfixExpression = postfixExpression.concat(infixExpChar+"");
            numberEnd = true;
            break;
        case ' ':
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Space in between expression is unacceptable", "Spacing Error", JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
            break;
        case '(':
            if(numberEnd == true){
                postfixExpression = postfixExpression.concat(" ");
                numberEnd = false;
            }else{
            stack.push(new Character('('));
            break;
            }
        case ')':
            if(numberEnd == true){
                postfixExpression = postfixExpression.concat(" ");
                numberEnd = false;
            }else{
                while(((Character)stack.peek()).charValue() != '('){
                    postfixExpression = postfixExpression.concat(((Character)stack.pop()).toString());
                }
            }Object openParenthesis = stack.pop();
            break;
        case '+':
        case '-':
        case '*':
        case '/':
            if(numberEnd == true){
                postfixExpression = postfixExpression.concat(" ");
                numberEnd = false;
            }
            while(!stack.isEmpty() && (((Character) stack.peek()).charValue()) != '(' && (Precedence(infixExpChar)) <= Precedence(((Character)stack.peek()).charValue())){
                postfixExpression = postfixExpression.concat(((Character)stack.pop()).toString());
            }
            stack.push(new Character(infixExpChar));
            break;
        }
    }if(numberEnd == true){
        postfixExpression = postfixExpression.concat(" ");
        numberEnd = false;
    }while(!stack.isEmpty()){
        postfixExpression = postfixExpression.concat(((Character)stack.pop()).toString());
    }
    return postfixExpression;
}

public static int Calculation(String postfixExpression) throws DivisionException{

    int value1, value2;
    String temporary = "";
    Stack stack = new Stack();

    for(int i = 0; i < postfixExpression.length(); i++){
        char postfixExpChar = postfixExpression.charAt(i);
        switch(postfixExpChar){
            case '0':
            case '1':
            case '2':
            case '3':
            case '4':
            case '5':
            case '6':
            case '7':
            case '8':
            case '9':
                temporary = temporary.concat(postfixExpChar+"");
                break;
            case ' ':
                stack.push(new Integer(temporary));
                temporary = new String();
                break;
            case '+':
                value1 = new Integer(((Integer)stack.pop()).intValue() + ((Integer)stack.pop()).intValue());
                stack.push(value1);
                break;
            case '-':
                value2 = new Integer(((Integer)stack.pop()).intValue());
                value1 = new Integer(((Integer)stack.pop()).intValue() - value2);
                stack.push(value1);
                break;
            case '*':
                value1 = new Integer(((Integer)stack.pop()).intValue() * ((Integer)stack.pop()).intValue());
                stack.push(value1);
                break;
            case '/':
                value2 = new Integer(((Integer)stack.pop()).intValue());
                value1 = new Integer(((Integer)stack.pop()).intValue() / value2);
                    if(value2 == 0){
                        throw new DivisionException();
                    }
                stack.push(value1);
                break;
        }
    }return (int) stack.peek();
}

public static int Precedence(char operator){
    int precedence = 0;
    switch(operator){
        case '+':
        case '-':
            precedence = 1;
            break;
        case '*':
        case '/':
            precedence = 2;
            break;
    }return precedence;
}

public static boolean checkParenthesis(String exp){
    Stack stack = new Stack();
    for (int i = 0; i < exp.length(); i++){
        char character = exp.charAt(i);
        if(character == '('){
            stack.push(new Character(character));
        }else if(character == ')'){
            if(stack.isEmpty()){
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Parenthesis does not match", "Parenthesis Error", JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
                return false;
            }else 
                return true;
        }
    }return stack.isEmpty();
}
}
```

//**DivisionException**

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
public class DivisionException extends Exception{
    public DivisionException(){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Cannot divide a number by 0", "Division Error", JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
    }
    }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Handling parenthesis while converting infix expressions to postfix expresssions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19721072/handling-parenthesis-while-converting-infix-expressions-to-postfix-expresssions)